# Test Error - Chapter 3.6 Adv Testing - RUBY ON RAILS 5 TUTORIAL - 4th Ed - M Hartl

Tags: railstutorial.org

Everything was rolling along fine using Cloud9 IDE - until ... in 3.6 I configured Advanced Testing and have not been able to debug it successfully? I could use some help. Newer to Rails ....
Thanks in Advance.

```
mcloudstack:~/workspace/sample_app (master) $ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 8379
Started with run options --seed 47305

ERROR["test_full_title_helper", ApplicationHelperTest, 0.011410524020902812]
 test_full_title_helper#ApplicationHelperTest (0.01s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `full_title' for #<ApplicationHelperTest:0x0000000386d230>
            test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'

ERROR["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 0.5379643210908398]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (0.54s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000000060dfb50>:0x000000060e3e80>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1744770820645383621_50825200'
            test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 0.5737704820930958]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (0.57s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x00000005169478>:0x0000000515de98>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1744770820645383621_42595720'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.6096331640146673]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.61s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000000060dfb50>:0x00000004a8ff08>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1744770820645383621_38997440'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.6480439120205119]
 test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.65s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000000060dfb50>:0x000000030fc730>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1744770820645383621_25230720'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_contact", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.692532810033299]
 test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.69s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000000060dfb50>:0x000000021e4bf8>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1744770820645383621_24873900'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.749511854024604]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.75s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000000060dfb50>:0x000000049c7e40>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1744770820645383621_30378000'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

  7/7: [=============] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.75916s
7 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 7 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined method full_title in your test. Pay attention, maybe there is a typo in youre code.